# Update Rows, column values represent as keys

Tags: mysql, eloquent

Here's the overview of my table.

[image]

The thing is, the value of `meta_key` column represent as keys.

The problem is, how would I update the fields with `user_id`. For example, I want to update gender, employee_type, division, mobile that has a different values each field that has a user_id of 1.

I really have no idea how though, but on Eloquent there's this `->insert()` to insert multiple values.

```
$meta_values = [
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'mobile', 'meta_value' => $mobile,],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'address', 'meta_value' => $address,],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'gender', 'meta_value' => $gender],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'birthday', 'meta_value' => Carbon::parse($birthday)->format('Y-m-d')],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'employee_type', 'meta_value' => $employee_type],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'division', 'meta_value' => $division],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'date_employed', 'meta_value' => Carbon::parse($date_employed)->format('Y-m-d')],
    ['user_id' => $user->id, 'meta_key' => 'avatar', 'meta_value' => $images->avatar]
];

$user->userMeta()->insert($meta_values);
```

Here's the insert version, but how's the update version going to be or what it looks like. Any ideas?

I think it would be possible by using loop, but I probably think that it would not be a great idea.

--- EDITED ---

For now, here's my temporary solution. Here's what I'm gonna do in the first place but, until someone has an answer to this problem, this is my solution for now.

```
//List all fields in an array to be updated
$meta_array = ['mobile', 'address', 'gender', 'birthday', 'employee_type', 'division', 'date_employed'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($meta_array); $i++) {

    $user->userMeta()
        ->where('meta_key', $meta_array[$i])
        ->update(['meta_value' => ${$meta_array[$i]}]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along this lines should work for you:

```
$meta_array = array('gender', 'employee_type', 'division', 'mobile');

Your\Model::where('user_id', 1)
            ->whereIn('meta_key', $meta_array)
            ->update(['meta_value' => 'some_new_value']);
```

The above PHP code should correspond to the following raw SQL query which you gave in your question as an example:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET meta_value='some_new_value'
WHERE user_id=1 AND meta_key IN ('gender', 'employee_type', 'division', 'mobile')
```

Comment: Thanks for your time answering, but wouldn't that mean that it will update all the fields with the same value? Sorry if my question isn't clear. I edited my question and, what should happen is, if possible to have different value per field.

Comment: Eloquent is just a thin wrapper around MySQL.  When you do an `UPDATE` you make the _same_ changes to _all_ columns specified, for a certain restricted set of records (rows).  So I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Thanks for that, seems I have to do it the messy way.